# "Accessory" pronounced with a stress on the first syllable

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, stress, canadian-english

I'm a first language English speaker, but grew up bilingual in Spanish in a Spanish speaking country. Today I was speaking to another first language English speaker (Canadian) and used the word "accessory" but the other person did not understand me. I changed the stress from the first syllable to the second and they finally understood. I thought this was because my English is more Americanized, and chalked it up to the difference with Canadian English. Curious, I looked up the pronunciation in the dictionary but it only offered the second syllable stress pronunciation as correct.

Have I been pronouncing it wrong all this time? I only use the first syllable stress version when talking about objects (an accessory for a camera, for example) but for some reason use the second syllable stress version in other situations (like "accessory to murder"). I cannot trace why I pronounce it the first way, so I have no idea where I learned to pronounce it that way (or why the other way in other contexts). Can anyone confirm if there are any regions (that use English as first language) that pronounce it the first way?

Comment: This could be because of something called as Mother Tongue Influence.

Comment: It was my first thought, but in Spanish, the accent is on the third syllable, not the first.

Comment: Maybe your Canadian friend was used to French, in which case... go figure... In English, we pronounce it as  {axe - seh - surrey}, with stress on the 2nd syllable, while in French, my best guess is {asseh-sary}, spoken without a syllable stress at all.

Comment: Nonetheless, whether it's on the first or third syllable, it's the same rhythm - one which is distinct from having the stress on the second syllable.

Comment: The answer is *yes*, you have been pronouncing it "wrong" all along, where "wrong" means not the way native English speakers generally pronounce it.

Comment: I do the same thing (native American English speaker) although I never noticed it before I read this question. It's very subtle, though. If someone can't understand you you're probably overdoing it.

Comment: @RoseofWords that's quite a relief to hear, I have become very self-conscious of this as of late. Would you happen to have a youtube/soundcloud/etc channel where you could upload a recording of what you sound like saying it? I am very curious to hear it and compare to how I say it. Also, what region of the US are you from?

Comment: My current working theory is that I pronounce it this way because of my pronunciation of the word "access", which is stressed on the first syllable, and therefore, "accessory" gets the first syllable stress too. "access sore 'e'"

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. My recommendation is that you ask a friend or two to listen to you saying it and see if they think that it sounds weird. I'm from New England, but I can't say for sure if it's a regional thing.

Comment: @RoseofWords, you can use this site: https://www.howtopronounce.com/accessory/ Let me know if/when you do, I'm really curious to hear it.

Comment: In the (U.S.) South, lots of nouns shift stress to the first syllable. I don't know whether *accessory* is one of these. But note that the rest of the U.S. thinks they pronounce many of these nouns wrong.

Comment: The two pronunciations I'm recalling (here in the US) are "ACK-sess-or-ee" (rare/odd) and "uh-SESS-or-ee" (common).  I would understand the first, but rarely if ever use it.

Comment: @HotLicks what region are you in?

Comment: @insaner - Upper Midwest (Minnesota), with a few roots in the "border states".  Fairly cosmopolitan/vanilla dialect here, as people are from all over the world, and it's an upper-middle-class region, for the most part.

Comment: Would you say there is some Germanic influence on the accent? Or something close to "Fargo"? Specifically when it comes to the first pronunciation.

Comment: @PeterShor Is the Southern pronunciation something like ACK-SESsory, with the first two syllables stressed and first syllable drawn out?

Comment: @Lawrence: Probably. Judging from [forvo](http://forvo.com/word/accessory/#en),  that seems to be a fairly common stress pattern for *accessory*. I don't actually know the Southern pronunciation for *accessory*; I just know they tend to accent the first syllable of a number of nouns the rest of us accent on later syllables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to have once been a pronunciation of "accessory" with the main accent on the first syllable, and no stress on the second syllable. Many polysyllabic words ending in "-ary" or "-ory" put the main accent two syllables before this ending (as in "**com**mentary" or "**in**ventory"). But some of these words have come to have the main accent on the first syllable before "-ary" or "-ory", and "accessory" is currently pronounced everywhere with this accentuation (as far as I can tell).

The Oxford English Dictionary says

> N.E.D. (1884) also gives the pronunciation (æ·ksėsəri) /ˈæksɪsərɪ/.

Walker's *[Critical Pronunciation Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n98/mode/2up/search/accessory)* (1791) only gives a single pronunciation, with the main accent on the first syllable. It is a prescriptive dictionary, but Walker usually noted when he was proposing a new pronunciation, and he doesn't say anything like that in this entry.

It's also mentioned in *[Correct Pronunciation, A Manual Containing Two Thousand Common Words that are Frequently Mis-pronounced, and Eight Hundred Proper Names, with Practical Exercises](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=a8sVAAAAYAAJ),* by Julian Willis Abernethy (1912)—as an incorrect pronunciation. (According to the preface, Abernathy intended to recommend only "the best current usage"). Abernathy cites "Worcester", which I guess would be J E Worcester, as the main "authority" he felt supported the pronunciation with the main accent on the first syllable. I don't know if the pronunciation was even common in Abernathy's time (making it one of the words he thought were "frequently mispronounced"), or if he just mentioned it because he had encountered it in some old dictionaries, and he wanted to advise people against using a pronunciation that he thought was outdated.

I don't know the distribution of this pronunciation in present-day English, or whether it represents a retention of the old accentuation pattern or an innovation based on some other tendencies (e.g. a general tendency to place the main accent on the first syllable of words, or analogy from the accentuation of "access"). I can't recall ever hearing it myself.

#### Possible stress on the first syllable when the second syllable is accented

Some of the comments beneath this question bring up a slightly different point. An English word can only have one *main* accented syllable (which is always a stressed syllable, and is often said to have the "primary stress"), but according to many analyses, there may be stressed syllables in a word other than the main accented syllable. (I found a document that seems to give a more complete explanation of English stress and accent, if you want to learn more about that: "[Sentential Prominence in English](http://www.companiontophonology.com/fragr_image/sentential)", by Carlos Gussenhoven.)

The vowel in the initial syllable of "accessory" is reduced to something like /ə/ for many speakers, but not all.

It may be that some speakers have the main accent on the second syllable, but also stress the first syllable, and consequently pronounce it as /æk/ with an unreduced vowel.

Or, it could be that to speakers who reduce the vowel, a pronunciation with unreduced /æ/ just sounds like it has some stress on the first syllable. There are arguments about what "stress" is in English, and where it occurs. (E.g. not everyone distinguishes "accent" from "stress" the way I've tried to do in this answer.)

Words that are derived from other words with a different accentuation pattern can sometimes have adjacent stressed syllables like this; I would say that another possible example of this is "activity", related to the adjective "active", and pronounced with unreduced /æ/ in the first syllable even though the second syllable of "activity" has the main accent.

I found a source that calls this "tertiary stress" ("[Word Stress – Part 1](http://gepeskonyv.btk.elte.hu/adatok/Anglisztika/43B%E9rces/Tank%F6nyv/Chapter8.pdf)", p 111), but in any case there is no consensus as far as I know about the names for different "levels" of stress in English. Probably the least controversial way of describing the difference between the pronunciations is by referring to the presence or absence of vowel reduction.

Answer (score 2):

> Have I been pronouncing it wrong all this time?

In North American pronunciation, the answer is yes, you have been pronouncing it wrong.

> Can anyone confirm if there are any regions (that use English as first language) that pronounce it the first way?

Just for kicks I tried a few other accents in ivona.com and I can confirm that the Australians and Brits also place the accent on the second syllable.

Answer (score 0):

I find the pronunciation of "accessory" with just a single stress on the first syllable very odd.  I would never say it that way -- it just doesn't sound like a possible American English pronunciation.  I don't know why, but I have a guess.

English stress is fundamentally dissimilatory -- syllables get stressed before an unstressed syllable, or, even more favorable to stress is the position before two unstressed syllables. That is what is odd about "ACCessory" -- there are three unstressed syllables in a row. One of the first two should have dissimilated and become stressed.

Yes, I know what you're thinking.  You know lots of words with three unstressed syllables in a row: "PRESidency", "ADvocacy", for instance.  But those are morphologically complex forms in which the vowels of certain morphemes lose their stress.  The Main Stress Rule in *The Sound Pattern of English* incorporates references to the specific morphemes At and Or, for instance.